# How to find the values of next array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

We know that find() method returns the value of the first array element that passes a test function.

But in the below case what if I need all the elements?

```
<p id="myPEle">
</p>

const listIds = ["Vanilla","Vanilla"];
const itemId = 'Vanilla';
for(let i=0; i< listIds.length; i++){
    const result = listIds.findIndex(id => id === itemId)
    document.getElementById("myPEle").innerHTML += result;
}
```

Well I need the result to be '01' instead of '00'

Comment: if you need all elements, then how about using `.filter`?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const listIds = ["Vanilla", "Vanilla"];
const itemId = 'Vanilla';

const result = listIds.filter(id => id === itemId) //use filter method
                      .map((item,index)=>index) //get array of index of filtered items
                      .join("");  //join array item

document.getElementById("myPEle").innerHTML = result ;
```

```html
<p id="myPEle"></p>
```

If listIds array is big in size the then I would suggest to use "array.reduce" instead of filter in order to avoid multiple iteration on array
which will perform filtering and mapping in one iteration
check for more on  [reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392307/what-does-the-reduce-javascript-function-do)

Comment: Shouldn't result should be array indexes, not values? " I need the result to be '01' instead of '00'"

Comment: @Ihor it's a bit unclear, to be honest. The title refers to values, the code sample uses the index. I'd normally follow the code sample but...it doesn't make much sense, it seems like OP is using it as a debug way to see which item was matched, not because the index is actually needed.

Comment: This could be done with only `forEach()`.....please check out my answer. Also you should think about the performance when changing the HTML in each iteration with `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

In both the iteration of the loop, you are getting the same index (`0`) because

> The [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.

You can use `forEach()` to check the item in each iteration. If the current item is equal to the `itemId`, you can store the index.

**Please Note:** To add text into an element it is better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
const listIds = ["Vanilla","Vanilla"];
const itemId = 'Vanilla';
listIds.forEach(function(el,i){
    if(itemId == el)
    document.getElementById("myPEle").textContent += i;
});
```

```html
<p id="myPEle">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Well I need the result to be '01' instead of '00'

If you really need to get indexes and not values - use `map` function.

```
const listIds = ["Vanilla","Vanilla"];
const itemId = 'Vanilla';
const result = listIds.map((id, index) => id === itemId && index)
                      .filter(x => x !== false); // Thanks @vlaz
console.log(result); // [0,1]
```

Otherwise - use `filter` method

```
const listIds = ["Vanilla","Vanilla"];
const itemId = 'Vanilla';
const result = listIds.filter(id => id === itemId);
console.log(result); // ["Vanilla","Vanilla"]
```

Comment: `id === itemId && index` - you would probably have to add an extra `.filter(x => x !== false)` otherwise for an input of `["Vanilla", "Fred", "Vanilla"]` you'd get `[0, false, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses `reduce` and `join` prototype methods. I added a couple of additional strings to `listIds` to show that it works:

```js
function generateIdxString(array, target) {
  return listIds.reduce((a, el, idx) => {
    if (el === itemId) {
      a.push(idx);
    }
    return a;
  }, []).join('');
}

const listIds = ["Vanilla", "Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla"];
const itemId = "Vanilla";

document.querySelector('#myPEle').innerHTML = generateIdxString(listIds, itemId);
```

```html
<p id="myPEle"></p>
```