# React Firebase : problem creating a chart

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, textarea

I'm coding a React articles app with  Firebase as  database.
I would like to create a chart with the days of the week as the X axis and the number of words written in the textarea in the Y axis. I was able to do everything except figure out how to put this data correctly in the chart.

```
import React from "react";
import Chartist from "react-chartist";
import ChartistTooltip from 'chartist-plugin-tooltips-updated';

import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'


import { db } from "../index";

export const SalesValueChart = () => {
  
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

  useEffect(() => {
    getArticles();
    console.log(articles.reduce(reducer, 0))
  }, []); // blank to run only on first launch

  function getArticles() {
    db.collection("notes").onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      setArticles(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().wordsCounted)  
      );
     
    });
  }

  const data = {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    series: [articles.reduce(reducer, 0)]
  };


  const options = {
    low: 0,
    showArea: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    axisX: {
      position: 'end',
      showGrid: true
    },
    axisY: {
      // On the y-axis start means left and end means right
      showGrid: false,
      showLabel: false,
      labelInterpolationFnc: value => `$${value / 1}k`
    }
  };

  const plugins = [
    ChartistTooltip()
  ]

  return (
     <Chartist data={data} options={{...options, plugins}} type="Line" className="ct-series-g ct-double-octave" />


  );
};

export const SalesValueChartphone = () => {
  const data = {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    series: [[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3]]
  };

  const options = {
    low: 0,
    showArea: true,
    fullWidth: false,
    axisX: {
      position: 'end',
      showGrid: true
    },
    axisY: {
      // On the y-axis start means left and end means right
      showGrid: false,
      showLabel: false,
      labelInterpolationFnc: value => `$${value / 1}k`
    }
  };

  const plugins = [
    ChartistTooltip()
  ]

  return (
    <Chartist data={data} options={{...options, plugins}} type="Line" className="ct-series-g ct-major-tenth" />
  );
};
```

..................................
..................................

Comment: Could you provide an example of `articles` array after `getArticles()` has been called? the prop `series` should be a 2d array with length of 7?

Comment: I get the  articles in an array shape as expected. But the problem is how can I change labels and series with words and Timestamp property of the articles saved in Firebase. Can you help me do this?

Comment: Are you using an external library to display the chart?

Comment: Yes I'm using Chartist. I've edited the post so now you view the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly:

1 - After the firebase call you can store in the state just the array with values

```js
    setArticles(
      querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().wordsCounted)
    );
```

2 - Now your data variable could be initialize like this

```js
      const data = {
        labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        series: [articles]
      };
```

N.B. if the API call retrieve a 2d array the prop `series` would be `series: articles` without `[]`

Comment: and I don't get anything in the console either

Comment: Is the DB retrieving information? @MarcoMarioni

Comment: What do you mean? If I understood well I'm just getting data from the DB, not adding them, so it's not retrieving anything

Comment: Apologies my question was ambitious, just want to know what's the console.log of  `querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().wordsCounted)`

Comment: I get an empty array

Comment: That's why is not showing datas @MarcoMarioni

Comment: How can we edit this line of code? querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().wordsCounted

Comment: Is `doc.data().wordsCounted` a value or is undefined or null?

Comment: In Firestore I have 4 articles with 'wordsCounted' equals to 2, 20, 50 and 45.

Comment: The name of the collection is 'todos'?

Comment: Oh shit it's actually called "notes", what a stupid mistake ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I want to do now is sum the 'wordsCounted' of an entire day and consider it as a single block, in such a way as to display the sum of the words written by the user in the all day. How can I do that?

Comment: @MarcoMarioni the reduce method could help you to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392307/what-does-the-reduce-javascript-function-do

Comment: I tried to use it but I'm not receiving any data. I edited the post so you can see how I've used it

Comment: Now `articles` is an array of numbers?

Comment: In theory yes, because before it displayed the 'wordsCounted' of every post when I called it

Comment: Could you make a console.log of `article` before the reduce?

Comment: I just noticed that I am getting this error with articles.reduce (reducer, 0)

Comment: chartist.js: 3430 Uncaught TypeError: data.normalized.series [seriesIndex] .forEach is not a function
      in constr. <anonymous> (chartist.js: 3430)
      in Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      on constr.createChart (chartist.js: 3412)
      at constr.initialize (chartist.js: 1930)

Comment: This is because `reduce` in your case is returning a number, maybe `series: [[articles]]` will fix it, but I think that this is not what you want to do.

Comment: It works. Actually this is what I want to do, but I would like to add the 'wordsCounted' of the articles of the same day and then do so with all the following days

Comment: Maybe I can use the 'timestamp' property of the article?