# Hello, I am new here and trying to learn a array method .reduce

Tags: javascript

```
function reduce(...args){
  
  args.reduce(function(takeMeOnlyOne,takeMeOnlyTwo){
    return takeMeOnlyOne + takeMeOnlyTwo;
    
  },1);
}

const IS_IT_REDUCING = reduce(1,2,3,4);

console.log(IS_IT_REDUCING)
```

Is the code ignoring `3,4` from `(1,2,3,4)` and what is the purpose for `.reduce(function(){ },1)`

What is the purpose of `1`?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)? Where is `red` defined? Where is `reduce` used? Your function `reduce` doesn’t return anything. `[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 1)` is `11`. How did you conclude that it is somehow “ignoring” `3` and `4`?

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong its reduce(1,2,3,4), I tried to read the documentation but I was getting complex examples with objects and things that is the documentation I wanted thx

Comment: Duplicate of [What does the Array method `reduce` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33392307/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

There is an error: your reduced function doesn't return anything.

I renamed the vars to make it more clear:

The purpose of `1` - it's a starting value.

```
const STARTS_WITH = 0 // try to replace it with -1 for example.

function reduce(...args){
  return args.reduce(function(elm, total){
    console.log('curr:', elm, ' total:', total)
    return elm + total; // added return
  }, STARTS_WITH); 
}

const IS_IT_REDUCING = reduce(1,2,3,4);
console.log(IS_IT_REDUCING)
```

Output would be:

```sh
curr: 0 ; total: 1
curr: 1 ; total: 2
curr: 3 ; total: 3
curr: 6 ; total: 4
result:  10
```

Try to replace `STARTS_WITH` with `-1` and you'll get `9` in the result.